# I would like to add (insert) column numbers (from 1 to 1000) at first column in the .CSV file

Tags: java, csv

For Example

My **input.csv** contains data like this..

**Row_No  ,User   , Actions**

John   , SQL transaction

Suman  , Transaction failed

Ram    , Button pressed to retrieve details

And this i what I am looking for.. Advance thanks to each one of you those who have tried this

**output.csv**

**Row_No  ,User   , Actions**

1       ,John   , SQL transaction

2       ,Suman  , Transaction failed

3       ,Ram    , Button pressed to retrieve details

please help me

**This is what I have tried**

```
public class MapWriter

{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    CsvMapReader mapReader = null;

    ICsvMapWriter mapWriter = null;

    try 
       
     {
     
        CsvPreference prefs = CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE;
     
        mapReader = new CsvMapReader(new FileReader("D:\\input.csv"), prefs);
        
        mapWriter = new CsvMapWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\output.csv"), prefs);

        // header used to read the original file
        
        final String[] readHeader = mapReader.getHeader(true);

        // header used to write the new file 
       
        // (same as 'readHeader', but with additional column)
        
        final String[] writeHeader = new String[readHeader.length + 1];
        
        System.arraycopy(readHeader, 0, writeHeader, 0, readHeader.length);
        
        final String timeHeader = "   ";
        
        writeHeader[writeHeader.length-1]= timeHeader;

        mapWriter.writeHeader(writeHeader);
       
        int count=1;
       
        Map<String, String> row;
        
        while( (row = mapReader.read(readHeader)) != null ) {
            
            // add your column with desired value
        
        row.put(timeHeader, String.valueOf(count));

        mapWriter.write(row, writeHeader);
            
            count++;  
        }
        
       
    }
    finally {
        if( mapReader != null )
        {
            mapReader.close();
        }
        
        if( mapWriter != null ) 
        {
            mapWriter.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Where's `CsvMapReader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to use a verifying CSV parser on invalid data (e.g. Row_No is blank everywhere but the header in your input file). I'm not certain if that's allowed with your parser, but I don't believe you need to parse the file yet. As an example, I would do it with [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) like so -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputFile = "c:/input.csv";
    String outputFile = "c:/output.csv";
    int lineNumber = 0;                    // <-- keep a line count.
    Scanner scanner = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(outputFile);  // <-- output
        File source = new File(inputFile);
        scanner = new Scanner(source);     // <-- input
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            line = (line != null) ? line.trim() : "";
            if (line.length() < 1) {
                continue;
            }
            // line 0 is the header.
            if (lineNumber != 0) {
                pw.print(lineNumber);
                pw.print(", ");
            }
            int tokenCount = 0;
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = st.nextToken();
                if (tokenCount != 0) {
                    pw.print(", ");
                }
                pw.print(token.trim());
                tokenCount++;
            }
            pw.println();
            lineNumber++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
        if (pw != null) {
            pw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

After running the above, I generated the `output.csv` (based on your `input.csv`) -

```
Row_No, User, Actions
1, John, SQL transaction
2, Suman, Transaction failed
3, Ram, Button pressed to retrieve details
```

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch, this is really useful, by this i learnt string tokenizer.. for this answer thumbs up...

Comment: Frisch, If there is no Header (Row_No ,User , Actions) ?? then whats modification?